# How to understand the some("a value") in Swift 4.1

Tags: swift4.1

Here is the screenshot of my Xcode Playground:

[image: Screenshot of Playground]

As you can see, the `str` is printed as `some("Hello")`. This really confuses me as there seems to be no documentation on it.

Dose anyone have a good explanation for this `some()`?

---

System info:

- swift -version: `4.1.2`
- Xcode: `9.4.1`

Comment: Do you know what is `Optional` for?

Comment: @nayem , yes. But I'm just a little confused on the printing `some()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a quirk in `print` for this compiler, purely conjecture it may be an artefact of work on changing the semantics of implicitly unwrapped optionals, see [Abolish `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` type](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md).

The type `Optional` is, stripping to the basics, defined as:

```
enum Optional<Wrapped>
{
   case none
   case some(Wrapped)
}
```

Normally if you `print()` an `enum` you do get the literals, here `none` and `some()`, however `print()` normally prints optionals as `nil` and `Optional()`.

It seems in Xcode 9.4.1 (at least) implicitly unwrapped optionals are being printed as optionals but without the special casing, whereas Xcode 9.2 (at least) prints the unwrapped value as would be expected (because it is implicitly unwrapped).

Maybe there is other interesting behaviour for implicitly unwrapped optionals in 9.4.1. You should test in Xcode 10 Beta and/or report a bug (bugreport.apple.com) in 9.4.1 and see what Apple say.

Comment: you are right. I tried this on Xcode 10 beta 2. The printing is `Optional("Hello")`.

Comment: @0xa6a - probably not worth filing a bug against 9.4.1 then. Of course with Swift being a moving target I'm not sure it ever has bugs, just behavior at a point in time ;-)